# Como filtrar linhas no R?

Tags: r, filtro

Boa tarde!
Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
1. Animal1 128kg  
2. Animal1 150kg  
3. Animal1 80kg  
4. Animal2 169kg  
5. Animal2 113kg
```

Como faço para filtrar para cada animal o peso mais próximo de 120kg e apagar as demas linhas?
- Como resultado eu teria apenas as linhas 1 e 5.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui estão três maneiras de fazer o que a pergunta pede, duas em R base e uma com o pacote `dplyr`.

**1. `aggregate`.**

```
aggregate(Peso ~ Animal, dados, FUN = function(x) x[which.min(abs(x - 120))])
#   Animal Peso
#1 Animal1  128
#2 Animal2  113
```

**2. `tapply`.**

```
p <- with(dados, tapply(Peso, Animal, function(x) x[which.min(abs(x - 120))]))
dados[dados$Peso %in% p & dados$Animal %in% names(p), ]
#   Animal Peso
#1 Animal1  128
#5 Animal2  113
```

**3. Pacote `dplyr`.**

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  mutate(Diff = abs(Peso - 120)) %>%
  group_by(Animal) %>%
  summarise(Peso = Peso[which.min(Diff)])
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Animal   Peso
#  <fct>   <dbl>
#1 Animal1   128
#2 Animal2   113
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!